# Flatlist component is not displaying the list

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Hello I am a beginner to react-native. I was practicing with a basic review app with stack navigation. I am trying to use the FlatList in Home Screen but it is not rendering. Here is my code.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Text, View, FlatList, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
import { globalStyles } from "../Styles/Global";

export default function Home({ navigation }) {
  const [reviews, setReviews] = useState([
    { title: "Zulqarnain", rating: 10, body: "Very Naughty Boy", id: "1" },
    { title: "Mubarak", rating: 8, body: "He's a good boy", id: "2" },
  ]);
  return (
    <View style={globalStyles.container}>
      <FlatList
        data={reviews}
        keyExtractor={(key) => key.id}
        renderItems={({ item }) => (
          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={() => navigation.navigate("ReviewDetails", item)}
          >
            <Text style={globalStyles.title}>{item.title}</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        )}
      />
      <Text style={globalStyles.title}> Home Screen</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: Have you checked my answer

Comment: Yes i got it bro Thankyou..:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
renderItems
```

to

```
renderItem
```